# Binding Air Mouse remote controller special keys in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings, keyboard-hook

I would like to remote control (Air Mouse) a WPF app.  The user can choose keys/buttons to do the special actions in the app settings.
I have implemented this functionality via the `KeyBinding` class, as shown below:

```
KeyBinding BindingNext = new KeyBinding() { Command = RemoteNext, 
Key = ((HotKey)key_choosen.key_value, Modifiers = ((HotKey)key_choosen.modifier_value };
this.InputBindings.Add(BindingNext);
```

where:

`public static RoutedCommand RemoteNext = new RoutedCommand();`

But I can't solve problems with the keys calling Win actions:

1. **Power button** (red circle on the controller). I can't capture this button. It always does the action specified in the power settings (sleep, power off...). I need to temporarily disable Windows default action while my program is running, without changing computer settings. Or ideally I need to completely change the action of this button as I wish.
2. **VolumeDown**, **VolumeUp**, **BrowserHome** (house icon) and etc. The key bindings work in this case but Windows also triggers system actions (raise and lower the volume, open browser). The only solution I have found is low-level global hooking by DllImport of the kernel functions. It does not look like a good solution for my problem. Can I achieve what I need using the "standard" (not low-level windows hooking) C#/WPF functions?